# Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-appcompat

this might be an experience for other developers of recent. I only experienced this today trying to build my app and i get this error.

> Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'android:actionModeCloseDrawable' with value
>   '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').

I googled and tried all suggested solutions but is nothing is working for me I even cloned back my initial project repository and can't seem to compile.

Any solution that works will help save time .

Answer (score 6):

In support library 23.2.0 the name was changed from abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha to abc_ic_ab_back_material. Could that be the problem?

Comment: It would be nice if they documented that somewhere :).  This broke my app.